# jQuery - add class to next element and remove it from current after some time

Tags: jquery

I need to do the "active" class will move from the first list item to next one after 3 sec ... stay there for 3 sec and then move to next one, after another 3 sec move to next ... and next, and next ...

when it comes to last one (list_4) hten it should start again from first li

I need ... if the list_3 has active class, class "block" with the same number should be visible, other "blocks" hidden or undisplayed (in this case block_3)

```
<ul>
 <li class="list_1 active"><a href="#">some text</a>
 <li class="list_2"><a href="#">some text</a>
 <li class="list_3"><a href="#">some text</a>
 <li class="list_4"><a href="#">some text</a>
</ul>
<div>
 <span class="block_1" style="display:block">some content</span>
 <span class="block_2" style="display:none">some content</span>
 <span class="block_3" style="display:none">some content</span>
 <span class="block_4" style="display:none">some content</span>
</div>
```

I want also to pause the "jumping" on ul:hover, when mouse goes out "jumping" shluld continue

Is tehre any not to complicated way to do that?

Comment: I need, I need, I need. What have you tried?

Comment: Hello try this http://jsfiddle.net/535u2/23 ... thanks goes to Sushil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following code may help you: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/535u2/)

```
     setInterval(function(){

           var active = $(".active").removeClass('active');
          if(active.next() && active.next().length){
                active .next().addClass('active');
    }
    else{
      active.siblings(":first").addClass('active');
    }

  }, 100);​
```

Comment: thanks that helps me to create half work ... see it here http://jsfiddle.net/535u2/14/, but I also want one more think, connect regular div to become active with same calss active li

Comment: thanks .. works great ... need to make some changes to fix divs dispaly after hover 

http://jsfiddle.net/535u2/23/

one more time thank you ... you make me smile after realy long time.