# Add class to list item alternately using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, alternate

I want to add an alternate class `visible` after 2 seconds to each element starting from `0` index. (like `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, ... until the end).

When it comes to the last element, then add class to backwards like (`10`, `9`, `8`, ... until `0`), so when on `0` again, forward and backward like an infinite loop. Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
$(function() {
  iterate();

  function iterate() {
    var i = 0;
    var plus = setInterval(function() {
      i++;
      if (i == 10) {
        clearInterval(plus);
      }
    }, 1000);

    var minus = setInterval(function() {
      i--;
      if (i == 0) {
        clearInterval(minus); // again start plus interval
      }
    });

    $('li').removeClass('visible');
    $('li').eq(i).addClass('visible');
  }
});
```

```css
.visible {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li class="visible">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Please be more specific.

Comment: How does **iterate** function called ?

Comment: Why do you need two intervals? Debug your code and see when $('li') is executed.

Comment: Well, I think, for loop might work, but I want to add class to next element or prev element after specific time always. Thanks

Comment: If someone give me JS Code, I'll be very thank full to him.

Comment: This question seems very similar to this one, see if that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918983/jquery-add-class-to-next-element-and-remove-it-from-current-after-some-time

Answer (score 2):

Try this: try below code where you can put logic to save current index and add / remove classes with `setInterval` function

```js
$(function () {    
   var i = $("ol li").length;   
   var j =0;
   var down = true;
   setInterval(function(){
      if(i==j || j<0) {
        down = !down;
        if(j<0) {
           j=0;
        }
      }
      if(down) {
        $("ol li").eq(j).addClass("visible");
        j++;
      } else {
        $("ol li").eq(j).removeClass("visible");
        j--;
      }
   }, 2000);
});
```

```css
 .visible {
        background: red
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   <li>Four</li>
   <li>Five</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, I really looking some thing like this. You are Great.

Comment: @MuhammadArshad, happy to help you :)